# How to calculate number of outfits from number of choices.for each part

Tags: combinatorics

Hi I have a simple question for a website.  My maths is rather rusty.  If hypothetically you have a number of select variants, for example you go to a website select the size, colour and t shirt type.  The colour has 2 options, size have 2 options and t shirt type you have 3 options.  How would I calculate the total number of combinations? Noting that different products will have different number of variants and each variant will have different number of options.  I am trying to remember my maths statistics and failing.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: If each size is not available in a different colours (so that some colours are not available for some sizes) and some types are not available depending on the size/colour, etc ... If this is true, then you manually have to calculate how many thare are, and there is no formula. But if all the options are available, then the rule of product can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth thinking about two variants first, e.g. suppose we have 4 sizes and 3 colours. You can think of this as a table/array/matrix:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
&s_1&s_2&s_3\\
\hline
c_1&(c_1,s_1)&(c_1,s_2)&(c_1,s_3)\\
c_2&(c_2,s_1)&(c_2,s_2)&(c_2,s_3)\\
c_3&(c_3,s_1)&(c_3,s_2)&(c_3,s_3)\\
c_4&(c_4,s_1)&(c_4,s_2)&(c_4,s_3)\\
\end{array}.$$

The entries in the tables are the possible combinations, so hopefully you can see that there are a total of $4\times 3=12$ combinations.

This idea works for more variants, e.g. in your case you have three variants, so you might image a 3-dimensional table (similar to a cube) which has a third dimension of attributes.

You can keep multiplying in this way to get the total number of combinations.

In your case you have $$2\times 2\times 3=12$$
combinations. But you may need to take into account repeated combinations.

Answer (score -1):

If categories (size,colour, t-shirt type) are independable, the resulting number of options is a simple product of options, i.e. 2 x 2 x 3 = 12

Comment: yes doh I realise that now sorry